# JSON Request returns null

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-fragments, android-volley

I am using Volley library on Android but when I make JSONArrayRequest, it automatically returns null. But if I keep debugging, in the second try it fills the array. Here are my codes:

> BackgroundTask.java

```
public class BackgroundTask{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Dua> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String json_url = "http://www.burakakyalcin.site/getDua.php";

    public BackgroundTask(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ArrayList<Dua> getList(){
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, json_url, (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                int count = 0;
                while(count<response.length()){
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
                        Dua dua = new Dua(jsonObject.getString("DuaId"),jsonObject.getString("DuaSender"),jsonObject.getString("DuaHeader"),
                            jsonObject.getString("DuaText"),jsonObject.getString("DuaLike"));
                        arrayList.add(dua);
                        count++;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
        return arrayList;
    }

}
```

> MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<Dua> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        arrayList = backgroundTask.getList();
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Dua> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Dua> arrayList){
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}


public void setArrayList (ArrayList<Dua> arrayList){
    this.arrayList=arrayList;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0, arrayList.size());
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.DuaSender.setText(arrayList.get(position).getDuaSender());
    holder.DuaHeader.setText(arrayList.get(position).getDuaHeader());
    holder.DuaLike.setText(arrayList.get(position).getDuaLike());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView DuaHeader, DuaSender, DuaLike;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        DuaHeader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.duaHeaderRec);
        DuaSender = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.duaSenderRec);
        DuaLike = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.duaLikeRec);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it returns null, and not an empty list on your first call?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin yes it returns empty list

Answer (score 2):

`JsonArrayRequest` is asynchronous.

When you call

```
arrayList = backgroundTask.getList();
```

First of all you'll get empty list:

```
ArrayList<Dua> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And only after HTTP calls succeeds, it will be populated. So, basically you need to wait for your result before using it.

```
public class BackgroundTask{

Context context;
Fragment fragment;
ArrayList<Dua> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
String json_url = "http://www.burakakyalcin.site/getDua.php";

public BackgroundTask(Context context, MyFragment fragment){
    this.context = context;
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

public void getList(){
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, json_url, (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
               // Map the JSON as you did before

               // Call your fragment
               fragment.setList(arrayList);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

In your fragment you need a setter method. Only when it's called you should render the list:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
ArrayList<Dua> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), this);


    return rootView;
}

public void setList(List<Dua> list) {
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

Comment: thanks nice point but I still have the error, when i first make JSON Array Request it automatically jumps to return arrayList which is empty, doesn't even go to onError or onResponse method. It fills the array after it returns rootview in the Fragment. After it fills, nothing happens.

Comment: You shouldn't have any "return arrayList" in your code. Please check my example again, and try to integrate in into your solution.

Comment: now I get "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" error. I have added my RecyclerAdapter class to question

Comment: I think that you should open a new question for the RecyclerView, as this question was about API calls.

Comment: btw in this code we don't call     BackgroundTask's     getList() method? Why?

Comment: Because you want to reverse the direction. When you call getList(), you don't know if the list is ready or not. The one who knows it is BackgroundTask. So, if BackgroundTask knows when the list is ready, it should call setList() instead. Get the idea?

Comment: okay but how a method could execute itself? we dont trigger anything to execute that method

Comment: Probably what confused you is that I named same method setList() and in the other setResult(). BackgroundTask should call MyFragment.setList()